# Help in debugging Exim4 SMTP AUTH 535 Incorrect authentication data

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp, exim

I followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/exim4.html#exim4-sasl) to set up TLS and auth. I have a username (usr) and a password (pwd) set in `/etc/exim4/passwd` and the files has the right permissions:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root        Debian-exim    51 Oct 16 13:11 passwd
```

If I remove the plain text part of the line in that file and run:

```
htpasswd -vb passwd usr pwd
```

then I get a nice

```
Password for user usr correct.
```

However, trying `openssl s_client -connect $HOST:25 -starttls smtp` and pasting:

```
ehlo test
250-example.org Hello example.org [1.2.3.4] ← Clearly, redacted…
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-CHUNKING
250-PRDR
250 HELP

auth plain AHVzcgBwd2Q=
535 Incorrect authentication data
```

Where the base64 is taken from:

```
echo -ne '\0usr\0pwd' | base64
AHVzcgBwd2Q=
```

I have run `systemctl restart exim4.service` and `update-exim4.conf` a fair few times.

***How to debug this?***

Comment: Show the full session, not just what you sent. E.g. the server should advertise AUTH in its capabilities after your EHLO.

Comment: @wurtel Added. It has AUTH enabled.

Comment: The exim mainlog should have a line logging that the authenticator failed. I can reproduce this error by supplying a wrong password. However as I use dovecot authentication, I don't have experience with the passwd file method. Check the mainlog for any messages. I use `log_selector = all` to make sure I get all possible messages.

Comment: @wurtel There is a log line in the log file but it does not tell me why the authentication failed, just that it did. The password encoding could be wrong I guess but that's the documentation I have.

Comment: The `AHVzcgBwd2Q=`  string is correct for user 'usr' with password 'pwd', so your testing method is correct, so it must be a problem with the authenticaion config in exim.

Comment: @wurtel I shall poke further… Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation lies](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/exim4.html) so do not listen to it.

What you need is to uncomment the `plain_server` driver in `conf.d/auth/30_exim4-config_examples` and comment out the `plain_saslauthd_server` and `login_saslauthd_server` garbage. *The saslauth driver do not work.*

From there onwards, it will work as expected.

[Source](https://debian-administration.org/article/631/Exim4_SMTP_Auth_for_the_Real_World).

Answer (score -2):

This works fine for me:

```
login_saslauthd_server:
   driver = plaintext
   public_name = LOGIN
   server_prompts = "Username:: : Password::"
   # don't send system passwords over unencrypted connections
   server_condition = ${if saslauthd{{${local_part:$auth1}}{$auth2}{}{${domain:$auth1}}}{1}{0}}
   server_set_id = $auth1
#   .ifndef AUTH_SERVER_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
   server_advertise_condition = ${if eq{$tls_in_cipher}{}{}{*}}
#   .endif
```